# Where can I get answers to other users question asked a long time ago, but both the asker and the answerer no longer have active accounts?

Tags: discussion

[When to use Inclusion Exclusion principle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40568/when-to-use-inclusion-exclusion-principle) I am not asking for clarification, but just to see if my answer is correct because neither the post nor the comments clearly state the answer to this question. All users on this post however are not active anymore so I feel no one will answer it. Should I make a separate question?

Comment: But if you do ask a new question, be sure to link to the old question(s) on inclusion-exclusion (there are probably dozens of them) and indicate why they aren't sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: Perhaps you feel that you yourself can answer the Question better than it already was?  It's hard to know what "just to see if my answer is correct", but one way to get feedback is to post a new Answer.